# Dynamic file hosting on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Windows Azure for a custom blog implementation. The blog uses CKEditor and the CKFinder file management plugin. Typically the file management plugin connects to a file system directory to store the files. I need to store these as if it was a local directory and serve them through HTTP requests. In Azure you cannot rely on the file system to maintain through recycles.

I assume you are to use Azure Storage, but am at a loss as to how to do this. Is there a way to "mount" these storage systems to the file system? Am I correct in my assumptions to use storage? If not any guidance as to what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually mount a page blob as an NTFS drive, which is then a "durable drive" (just like any other blob), and you access it via a drive letter, just like a locally-attached (but volatile) drive.

The issue is that, using mounted drives, you may only have one writer, so this might cause challenges when scaling to multiple instances.

Take a look at [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.mount.aspx) to see an example of mounting a drive. Notice that, while the example doesn't set up any cache, you can specify a cache size. The cache is stored on a local disk resource.

EDIT: For a tutorial, download the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396). Go to **hands-on labs**, and open **Exploring Windows Azure Storage**. Check out **Exercise 4: Working with Drives**.

Comment: I don't have the ability to modify code in this application, can this be used without any writing custom code?

Comment: You have to write code in your role's OnStart(), to set up the cloud drive mounting, and obtain the drive letter. You have to somehow tell your app what drive letter to use. But you don't have to modify your code to this.

Comment: This ended up being the exact response, which is not a solution, but rather clarifying a limitation. I was able to mount drive an read/write to it, but only on one instance. Preserving the up-time guarantee is more important that that persistent storage. I ended up utilizing the Azure CDE to store these files.

Comment: CkFinder and CkEditor in particular will have many writers active - loading a virtual drive and writing it back to Azure every time is not just grossly inefficient, but is guaranteed to cause concurrency issues and lost data.

Comment: @Sora2455 - you're commenting on something I posted *nine years ago*. Azure looked completely different back then (virtual machines hadn't even been announced yet). In early 2012, this was the one option available, whether "grossly inefficient" or not. And I have no idea why you're posting here talking about guarantees of data loss - you can go back in time and look up Azure Drives to dig further, but... not relevant to this now-ancient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use AzureBlobDrive to mount blob storage as a drive in Azure directly (no VHD, no limitation on only one instance being able to write).

https://github.com/richorama/AzureBlobDrive